# Finding the angle between a point and another point with an angle

Tags: vectors

To preface - I am not from a mathematics background, so I was unsure what this is actually *called* so I couldn't really look it up.  Please let me know if it is a duplicate / against the rules as I am a first time poster.

I have a scenario where there is an origin point, and then a character with a position and rotation.  I am trying to figure out how to get the angle between a ray cast from the rotation and position of the character to a ray cast from the origin point to the character.

[image]

In this image, I am trying to solve for the green arc's angle.  I have tried various solutions with basic trig, but they aren't always reliable when dealing with the other three possible quadrants.  (Also note that in these cases 0 degrees is "up").

Calculating an angle would be easy, but I am stuck since the blue point can keep the same angle, but change position.

E.g., the image below has the same character direction as the above of 20 degrees, but a different position.

[image]

From what I've tried to research, I've gotten a vague feeling that I should be looking to use something called a "dot product".  If you do have an answer, may I ask that it be simple and explanatory?  As I said, I am not proficient in this sort of math.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What exactly is known/given and how are things represented? In particular, I'm wondering how the rotation of the blue point is happening; it seems like you already know, in advance, what the rotation has to be.

Comment: I've added an image of the actual use case. I have a sprite with a variable rotation (but I always know what that angle is) as well as its exact position and position of the arbitrarily set origin.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: OK, I see, you always know the angle of the blue ray, where $0^\circ$ is "up" (correct me if I'm wrong). I assume here that the red angle is measured counterclockwise.

Comment: Correct - I'm measuring the difference between the current angle and "up".  So 90deg is right, 180deg is down, etc.

Comment: Er wait, I apologize.  I just took another look and it seems this particular engine handles 0deg as "right", -90 as "up", and etc.  Though it's the same principle I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word of caution: It's highly possible that *something* is off here, with the frame-of-reference being not quite what I'm used to. Hopefully the ideas are something you can implement and test with a variety of cases to see if something funny happens, with your particular situation. (If anything, I suspect with angles measured clockwise, we might have that $\varphi$ below comes back as $-\varphi$ or something).

[image]

I've uploaded another picture with a useful angle marked. If the coordinates of the blue point are $(x, y)$, then the red angle, called $\varphi$ here, can be computed using the $\operatorname{atan2}$ function; that is, $\varphi = \operatorname{atan2}(x, y)$.

Note that *both* red angles in the picture are $\varphi$.

In the picture, we can see that the green arc is made up of three nice angles:

$$\text{Green Angle} = \varphi + 90^\circ + A,$$ where $A$ is the known angle labeled $20$ in the picture.

---

A note on [$\operatorname{atan2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2): You want your language to have an $\operatorname{atan2}$ function. This is because you need inverse trig functions to find angles, but trig functions are notorious for having "finicky" inverses: if you don't know exactly what you're doing with an inverse trig function, it's easy to get the wrong result half the time. And thus, $\operatorname{atan2}$ was born, it's designed to be very user-friendly :)

Comment: Although with $0^\circ$ measured to the right, perhaps the $20^\circ$ angle should be "the other side" of the blue line; in this case, we'd have that the green angle is $180^\circ - A + \varphi$.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm starting to see how this is constructed.  With the `atan2` function, are the values for `x` and `y`the coordinates of the character?  Would this still work if my first point was moved to a place other than 0,0?  I've put what I think is the correct equation described into my program, but I'm getting values that exceed 360deg, which I imagine isn't correct, so I am probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Assuming the blue spaceship dot is the character, yeah, those are its coordinates. If the second point isn't $(0,0)$ but instead $(a, b)$, then it would be `atan2` of their difference: `atan2(x-a, y-b)` (I think: its late and I'm on a phone now). Angles more than $360^\circ$ do seem out of place. But probably you're not doing anything wrong, instead the formula needs "calibrating" to deal with minus signs etc. Hopefully the *diagram* helped you with ideas about how to find your angle; if it's still being finicky tomorrow I can try and think about what could be going wrong.

Comment: I'll take another crack tomorrow as well.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Update: got it to work :)

Comment: Hey, nice work, what a happy ending!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the origin is $(0, 0)$ and that your character (blue dot) is located at $(a, b)$, and that the character's angle of rotation (clockwise from "up") is $\theta$. From the character's perspective, we can construct two vectors:

- A (unit) vector that points in the direction of the character's line of sight: $\vec u = (\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$.
- A vector that points in the direction of the origin: $ \vec v = (-a, -b)$.

We want the angle $\phi$ between $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, and we can indeed use the dot product to compute it via the formula:
$$
\phi = \arccos\left( \frac{\vec u \cdot \vec v}{|\vec u||\vec v|} \right) = \arccos\left( \frac{-a\sin\theta - b\cos\theta}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \right)
$$

---

Applying this to your examples, we have:

- $\phi = 155^\circ$ if $a = 5, b = 5, \theta = 20^\circ$
- $\phi \approx 178.2^\circ$ if $a = 5, b = 2, \theta = 20^\circ$